# Sending locally stored image in hero card in Microsoft BotFramework

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a image in my project directory. I need to display that image in hero card. Is it only possible to add images to hero cards from a URL?

**If not how to add locally stored image in hero card or it is possible to choose any other card like adaptive which can use ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the image into base64 and add it to your hero card. Use the fs package to create a bitmap of your image, create a new Buffer object with the bitmap, and convert the buffer to a base64 string. See the code snippets below for more details. Note, the file path must be the absolute path to the image.

**Encode Image**

```
const fs = require('fs');

function encodeBase64(path) {
    const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(path);
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64')
}
```

**Create HeroCard**

```
createHeroCard(image, imageType='jpg') {
    return CardFactory.heroCard(
        'BotFramework Hero Card',
        CardFactory.images([`data:image/${imageType};base64,${encodeBase64(image)}`, 'http://localhost:3978/dog.jpg']),
        CardFactory.actions([
            {
                type: 'postBack',
                title: 'Button',
                value: 'Button'
            }
        ])
    );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, it is working fine. But in the above method you should convert imageToBase64(path) to encodeBase64 because you define the function with one name and call them as another name.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out - meant to change it. I've updated the code samples in my answer.